# iOS Accessibility hide the "textField, double tap to edit" announcement

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, accessibility, voiceover

I have a textField with a pickerView as the inputView.

Now when I have the voiceover on and select the textField, the voiceover will read this: "Quantity: 3 (content of the textField)", then "textField", then "Double tap to edit".

Is there anyway to make the voiceover just reads the content and skip the following "textField. Double tap to edit"?

I have tried to give the textField another UIAccessibilityTraits/Hints and they are not working.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a UILabel instead?  If the text is editable, you should have these announcements.  If not, you're using the wrong type of control...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, again! lol

This kind of textField is used everywhere in the app already and there are rightViews etc, so it's a lot of work to change all of them to labels.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming your text field is a subclass of UITextField, you're looking for the static text trait.

```
UITextField* aTextField = .....
aTextField.accessibilityTraits |= UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText;
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer!

Can't believe it's hiding in the UIAccessibilityTraits.

I tried to change the trait to button and it was announcing "button, textfield".

Also tried to set it to none and it was still announcing "textfield"

Thanks ChrisCM, AccessibilityMaster!

Comment: this answer should be aTextField.accessibilityTraits |= UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText

Answer (score 11):

## In Swift

```
let textField = UITextField()
textField.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText
```

*The example code in this answer was written and tested in Swift 3.

### About the `accessibilityTraits` Property

The `accessibilityTraits` property is a `UInt64` [bitmask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)). UIKit includes [named UInt64 constants](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1657063-uiaccessibility/1657255-accessibility_traits) such as `UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText` for ease in remembering which bits represent which settings.

When a UITextField is created, its `accessibilityTraits` property is set to "262144" which is "1000000000000000000" in binary. That means the 19th bit from the right signifies "text field". There is not a constant for this setting. I tried but could not figure out how to set the 19th bit to zero. This bit appears protected from editing by the implementation for UITextField. You could subclass UITextField and override the accessibilityTraits property to take full control of it like this...

**Overriding accessibilityTraits**

```
private var _accessibilityTraits: UInt64 = 0
override var accessibilityTraits: UInt64 {
    get {
        return _accessibilityTraits
    }

    set {
        _accessibilityTraits = newValue
    }
}
```

### Using UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText

If the "text field" flag is on or "1" then VoiceOver will announce "text field". As @ChrisCM posted, if the "static text" flag is also on, it cancels out the "Text Field" flag and VoiceOver does not announce anything for the type of control.

The "static text" flag is set by adding decimal "64" doing a bitwise OR of binary "1000000" to the accessibilityTraits property. The `UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText` constant makes this value easy to remember.

This code illustrates what is happening:

**Adding `UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText` to `accessibilityTraits` in detail**

```
let textField = UITextField()
print("original textField.accessibilityTraits, binary: \(String(textField.accessibilityTraits, radix: 2)), decimal: \(textField.accessibilityTraits)")

print("UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText, binary: \(String(UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText, radix: 2)), decimal: \(UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText)")
textField.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText

print("modified textField.accessibilityTraits, binary: \(String(textField.accessibilityTraits, radix: 2)), decimal: \(textField.accessibilityTraits)")
```

**Console Output:**

```
original textField.accessibilityTraits, binary: 1000000000000000000, decimal: 262144
UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText, binary: 1000000, decimal: 64
modified textField.accessibilityTraits, binary: 1000000000001000000, decimal: 262208
```

### `|=` Operator

The following also works. The `|=` operator takes the existing value and does a bitwise OR with "1000000". Since the original value of the `UITextField` `accessibilityTraits` is protected, this is not necessary.

```
textField.accessibilityTraits |= UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText
```

### Assigning a Different Trait

To assign a different trait such as a "button", bitwise OR `UIAccessibilityTraitButton` like this:

```
textField.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText | UIAccessibilityTraitButton

print("modified textField.accessibilityTraits, binary: \(String(textField.accessibilityTraits, radix: 2)), decimal: \(textField.accessibilityTraits)")
```

**Console Output:**

```
modified textField.accessibilityTraits, binary: 1000000000001000001, decimal: 262209
```

In this case `UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText` cancels out "text field" while `UIAccessibilityTraitButton` adds "button"

Comment: Thanks, great explanation ! Added information about the traits values and their basic operations are available at this a11y site : http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#element-trait

Comment: The `|` syntax doesn't seem to work anymore. I use array `textField.accessibilityTraits = [.button, .staticText]`